Почему данные через Sequelize не возвращаются корректно?
Пишу бэкенд на экспрессе и столкнулся с такой бедой:
Через Sequelize делаю обычный запрос на получение списка ролей пользователя, чтобы прогнать их через middleware, но вот незадача, тот же самый код, одна и та же база, но при запуске дев версии через npm run dev данные Groups и Roles не пустые, а при запуске прод версии в докере, данные уже undef.
"sequelize": "^6.37.4"
вывод groups:
api           |User {
api           |   dataValues: {
api           |     id: 9,
api           |     login: '***',
api           |     firstname: '***',
api           |     lastname: '***',
api           |     mail: '***',
api           |     avatar: '***',
api           |     createdAt: 2024-10-31T08:25:49.349Z,
api           |     updatedAt: 2024-10-31T08:25:49.349Z,
api           |     Groups: [ [Group], [Group] ]
api           |   },
api           |   _previousDataValues: {
api           |     id: 9,
api           |     login: '***',
api           |     firstname: '***',
api           |     lastname: '***',
api           |     mail: '***',
api           |     avatar: '',
api           |     createdAt: 2024-10-31T08:25:49.349Z,
api           |     updatedAt: 2024-10-31T08:25:49.349Z,
api           |     Groups: [ [Group], [Group] ]
api           |   },
api           |   uniqno: 1,
api           |   _changed: Set(0) {},
api           |   _options: {
api           |     isNewRecord: false,
api           |     _schema: null,
api           |     _schemaDelimiter: '',
api           |     include: [ [Object] ],
api           |     includeNames: [ 'Groups' ],
api           |     includeMap: { Groups: [Object] },
api           |     includeValidated: true,
api           |     attributes: [
api           |       'id',        'login',
api           |       'firstname', 'lastname',
api           |       'mail',      'avatar',
api           |       'createdAt', 'updatedAt'
api           |     ],
api           |     raw: true
api           |   },
api           |   isNewRecord: false,
api           |   Groups: undefined,
api           |   id: undefined,
api           |   login: undefined,
api           |   firstname: undefined,
api           |   lastname: undefined,
api           |   mail: undefined,
api           |   avatar: undefined,
api           |   createdAt: undefined,
api           |   updatedAt: undefined,
api           |   Roles: undefined
api           |}

вот сам запросик
    const groups = await User.findByPk(userData._id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: Group,
          through: {attributes: []},
          where: {valid: true},
          include: [{
            model: Role,
            where: {valid: true},
            attributes: ['name'],
            through: {attributes: []},
            include: [
              {
                model: RoleGroup,
                attributes: ['permission'],
              },
            ]
          }]
        },
      ],
    });
    return groups;


Решил проблему банально: Определяя классы моделей не убрал публичные поля, на это ругался sequelize и бил ошибку.
